# Wrap std::vector of std::vectors, C++ SWIG Python

Tags: c++, python, vector, swig

I want to wrap a C++ vector of vectors to Python code by using SWIG.

Is it possible to wrap this type of vector of vectors?

```
std::vector<std::vector<MyClass*>>;
```

In the interface file `MyApplication.i` I added these lines:

```
%include "std_vector.i"
%{ 
#include <vector> 
%} 

namespace std {
   %template(VectorOfStructVector) vector<vector<MyClass*>>;
}
```

But, I'm getting an Error when SWIG is executed. I'm able to wrap this type (using reference to the vector):

```
 std::vector<std::vector<MyClass*>*>;
```

But, it's not working properly, I cannot access  the items. That's why I'm interested in this type (without the reference):

```
 std::vector<std::vector<MyClass*>>;
```

Any ideas?

Comment: If this really is C++ and not C++0x, please make sure you include a space between the closing angle brackets. eg `>>` should be `> >`

Comment: I was debating to comment or answer...

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3754922/how-to-wrap-a-c-vector-of-vector-with-swig ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is it a C++ parsing issue?

```
 std::vector<std::vector<MyClass*> >;
 ---Important space---------------^
```

Comment: Also this line was needed in the interface file: %template(VectorOfStructVector) vector<vector<MyClass*> >;

Comment: @Javier, another solution is to compile with "--std=c++0x" if you're using gcc.  C++0x has fixed this problem.